# File copier is printing out my whole excerpt, I want it to do it line by line with user input between

Tags: java, io

I need my program to print this file line by line, waiting for the user to press enter between each one. My code keeps printing the whole excerpt. What do I need to change?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class NoteCopier {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Hello! I copy an excerpt to the screen line for line"
                        + " just press enter when you want a new line!");
    try {
        File file = new File("excerpt.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStreamReader inreader = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inreader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while(true) {
                String scanString = scan.nextLine();
                if(line != null) {
                if(scanString.isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                else {
                    scanString = null;
                    break;
                }
            
            }
        }
    }
        
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be printing lines from the file line by line for each Enter. Do you have more than one line in your file or it is a big excerpt in a single line?

Comment: i have a super long exceprt

Comment: What do you mean by "super long excerpt"? How long are the text lines in your excerpt? What is the output of `byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("excerpt.txt")); for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) { if (b[i] == 10 || b[i] == 13) { System.out.println(i); break; } }`? Note that `reader.readLine()` reads a complete line until the first line break character, it doesn't to any "softwrap" like some text editors can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If line is null you'll loop forever; the nested if statements.

I did it in the new Stream style, without the ubiquitous but needless Scanner on System.in.

```
private void dump(String file) {
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    BufferedReader con = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try (Stream<String> in = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        AtomicInteger lineCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        in.forEach(line -> {
            System.out.println(line);

            if (lineCounter.get() == 0) {
                String input = null;
                try {
                    input = con.readLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                if (input == null) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                } else if (input.equals(" ")) {
                    lineCounter.set(10);
                }
            } else {
                lineCounter.decrementAndGet();
            }
        });
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("< Stopped.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> you can exit on Windows I believe.
I have added that a line with a <kbd>Space</kbd> will dump the next 10 lines.

The ugly thing are the user input lines.

---

With [`java.io.Console`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) one can ask input with a String prompt, which then can be used to print the file's line as prompt.

```
private void dump(String file) {
    Path path = Paths.get(file);
    Console con = System.console();
    try (Stream<String> in = Files.lines(path, Charset.defaultCharset())) {
        AtomicInteger lineCounter = new AtomicInteger();
        in.forEach(line -> {
            if (lineCounter.get() == 0) {
                //String input = con.readLine("%s |", line);
                String input = new String(con.readPassword("%s", line));
                if (input == null) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                } else if (input.equals(" ")) {
                    lineCounter.set(10);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(line);
                lineCounter.decrementAndGet();
            }
        });
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("< Stopped.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Using a prompt with the file's line, and asking a non-echoed "password" will be sufficient okay. You still need the <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There is one problem: you must run this as real command line. The "console" in the IDE uses `System.setIn` which will cause a null Console. I simply create a .bat/.sh file. Otherwise `System.out.print(line); System.out.flush();` might work on some operating system.